# Connecting an SQlite database using classic asp.net

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, asp-classic, odbc

I am trying to connect my sqlite db using classic asp.net. I have downloaded and installed the ODBC driver from the following link:

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

I followed this tutorial to help me:
http://web.synametrics.com/SQLite.htm

I am now trying to make a connection to the database using the following function:

```
 function getDBConnection() {
  var DBCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
  var ConStr = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver; Database=C:\Web Authoring2\simpleCMS\DB\mydb.db; LongNames=0; Timeout=1000; NoTXN=0; SyncPragma=NORMAL; StepAPI=0;";
  DBCon.Open(ConStr);
  return DBCon;
}
```

This however isn't working and I'm getting a connection error.

Comment: It should start with `DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;` See:[sqlite3 odbc driver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite3-odbc-driver/)

Comment: There's no such technology as "Classic asp.net", Classic asp and asp.net are very different.  Your code looks like classic asp, using JScript rather than VBScript

Comment: I updated it but I still can't get it to work

Comment: The error I am getting is this: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

connect failed